# Draw Triangle Clipping Shape using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have to make a logo shape in my website. The design is given below. How do I develop that?

[image]

For the first part of the logo I have created it using CSS3 skew property,
I have fiddled the link below. How do I develop the triangle section and the third part of the logo. The triangle is slider, so images inside should change.

https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/x2og8utk/1/

```css
    .logo-menu {
        height: 76%;
        left: 11%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .first-part {
        display: inline-block;
        left: 135px;
        position: relative;
        transform: skew(-22deg);
        width: 180px;
    }
    .menu-1{
        background:red
    }
    .menu-2{
        background:blue
    }
    .menu-3{
        background:yellow
    }
```

```html
    <div class="logo-menu">
    <div class="first-part">
        <div class="menu-1" style="height: 167px;">
             <h3>About Us</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-2" style="height: 167px;">
             <h3>Gallery</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-3" style="height: 167px;">
             <h3>Get in Touch with</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: post the code for you triangle what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS transforms to rotate and skew an element into a diamond, and then reverse those transforms for the child elements. If you have `overflow: hidden;` on the diamond and position the diamond in a wrapper that also has `overflow: hidden;`, you could produce a clipping triangle with content using just CSS.

## Working Example ([Codepen](http://codepen.io/alexanderomara/pen/RNzNmE)):

```css
/* Clip the bottom half of the diamond. */
.triangle-wrap {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
/* Rotate and skew to create a diamond. */
.triangle {
 background: grey;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -50%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg);
         transform: rotate(45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg);
}
/* Reset the skew and rotation. */
.triangle-reset {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg) rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg) rotate(-45deg);
     -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg) rotate(-45deg);
         transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg) rotate(-45deg);
}
/* Create a content wrapper. */
.triangle-content {
 background: url('http://placehold.it/400x400') no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 width: 120%;
 height: 120%;
 left: -10%;
 bottom: 65%;
}

/* Visual aid. */
html {
 min-height: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #336666 0%,#663366 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-wrap">
 <div class="triangle">
  <div class="triangle-reset">
   <div class="triangle-content">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this part is working fine can you make the third part also ? is there anyway

Answer (score 1):

`background-clip` is what you're looking for. Check out this great article:

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Here's an online tool to help you generate shapes:

http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

After you generate each shape, you can position them to look like your image.

Comment: Hi I have checked clipping, for this shape I need to use polygon clipping unfortunately it is not supported by mozilla firefox

Comment: ie has no suport even in ie10+

Answer (score 1):

It is not perfect what you want but near to that.
Right side first div not looking good.

```css
.third-part {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 500px;
    position: relative;
    transform: skew(22deg);
    width: 180px;
}


.logo-menu {
    height: 76%;
    left: 11%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
.first-part {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 135px;
    position: relative;
    transform: skew(-22deg);
    width: 180px;
}
.menu-1{
    background:red
}
.menu-10{
     
   background: blue;
   /* Skew */
   
  left: -70px;
    position: relative;
    transform: skew(50deg);
    width: 190px;
}
.menu-2{
    background:blue
}
.menu-3{
    background:yellow
}

.second-part {
    top: 36%;
}
.second-part {
    
}
.second-part {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    width: 520px;
}
.second-part .triangle-shape {
    left: 4%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
}
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 240px 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transition: transform 300ms ease-out 0s;
    width: 500px;
}
.crop {
    height: 465px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transform: skew(22deg, 22deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    width: 450px;
}
.crop img {
    height: 650px;
    left: -50%;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg) rotate(-45deg);
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 500px;
}
}
.second-part .triangle-shape {
    left: 4%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
}
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 240px 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transition: transform 300ms ease-out 0s;
    width: 500px;
}
.crop {
    height: 465px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transform: skew(22deg, 22deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    width: 450px;
}
.crop img {
    height: 650px;
    left: -50%;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg) rotate(-45deg);
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-menu">
<div class="first-part">
    <div class="menu-1" style="height: 167px;">
         <h3>About Us</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-2" style="height: 167px;">
         <h3>Gallery</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-3" style="height: 167px;">
         <h3>Get in Touch with</h3>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="second-part">
        <div class="triangle-shape">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="crop">
                    <img alt="" src="http://s23.postimg.org/wlo0phrsb/triangle01.jpg">
                 <h2>Projects</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>   
    <div class="third-part">
    <div class="menu-10" style="height: 120px;">
         <h3>Products</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-2" style="height: 167px;">
         <h3>Services</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-3" style="height: 167px;">
         <h3>Location Map</h3>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help to move forward.

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/x2og8utk/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVG (http://www.w3schools.com/svg/) to draw and position the shapes and then apply CSS over them like color and backgound to get the desired results.